# Compare 2 arrays in PHP with checkbox checked (keep stucture)

Tags: php

I need to compare 2 arrays one from database with available cloth Sizes 
and a default Size

```
$sizedefault = array('s','m','l','xl','xxl','xxxl','xxxxl','xxxxxl'); // Default Sizes
$sizeavailable = explode(',',$pd_size);    // Available Sizes (db) s,m,l,xl

$available = array_diff($sizedefault , $sizeavailable );
$notavailable = array_intersect($sizeavailable , $sizedefault);
$output = "";
foreach ($notavailable as $value){
$output .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"size[]\" id=\"$value\" value=\"$value\" checked=\"checked\"/><label for=\"$value\">".$value."</label>";

}
foreach($available as $value){
$output .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"size[]\" id=\"$value\" value=\"$value\" /><label for=\"$value\">".$value."</label>";
}
```

that works so far but, the output is not sorted after i check eg: "xxxxl" and submit/request

i get this result:    (x) = checked

> s(x) m(x) l(x) xl(x) xxxxl(x) xxxxxl() xxl()

how can i keep them sorted as `$sizedefault`?

> s(x) m(x) l(x) xl(x) xxl() xxxxl(x) xxxxxl()

Comment: Why would the output be sorted if you print the two arrays one after the other?

Comment: thats what i´m asking m8, how could i receive a sorting....... is there another way to comapre/check ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to build those arrays beforehand - you could use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check for the value's existence in the availability array while your loop runs. It's better also because you don't have to duplicate the HTML code for your checkbox, the only difference is the presence of the `checked="checked"` and you can add that conditionally.

```
$sizedefault = array('s','m','l','xl','xxl','xxxl','xxxxl','xxxxxl'); // Default Sizes
$sizeavailable = explode(',',$pd_size);    // Available Sizes (db) s,m,l,xl

$output = "";
foreach ($sizedefault as $value){
    $checked = in_array($value, $sizeavailable) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $output .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"size[]\" id=\"$value\" value=\"$value\" $checked /><label for=\"$value\">".$value."</label>";
}
```

If `$sizedefault` comes from an external source (eg. a user, cookie, anything like that), or came from an external source previously before saving to the database, you should also escape the values inside it before printing it into HTML. You can do that with `htmlspecialchars()`. Otherwise people would be able to inject scripts into your HTML.

```
foreach ($sizedefault as $value){
    $checked = in_array($value, $sizeavailable) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    $output .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"size[]\" id=\"$value\" value=\"$value\" $checked /><label for=\"$value\">".$value."</label>";
}
```

Comment: @manga Please also read the parts about escaping that I just added. If you are satisfied with my answer you can accept it with the tickmark next to my answer.

Comment: usefull info thx , i have in my config.php as $sizedefault not taken from req/cookie val